# Eager loading child properties using LINQ to CRM

Tags: linq, sdk, dynamics-crm-4

Is there anyway I can eager load **client defined** child properties on a CRM entity using the LINQ to CRM Provider supplied in SDK 4.0.12?  I'm looking for something the same as the pattern in Entity Framework [as shown here](http://www.dansoltesz.com/post/2010/01/26/Entity-Framework-Dynamic-Include-statement.aspx).  I'd love to be able to do this so we can align our repository interfaces with those we already have against EF.

As an aside, I know I can do it client side via a WCF Data Service exposing my DataContext and then use the .Expand() extension method.  Therefore, it doesn't seem like such a stretch to allow me to perform the same at the server.